# How to delete last record(on condition) from a table in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a **LoginTime** table like this:

```
id | user_id | datetime
1  |   1     | 2011-01-17 18:51:05
2  |   1     | 2011-01-18 18:51:05  
3  |   1     | 2011-01-19 18:51:05  
4  |   2     | 2011-01-19 18:51:05
```

I want to delete last record for `user_id=1`. Last record of a user can be recognized by `datetime`.

How can I do this with one query.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to filter the table by user_id (eg WHERE user_id=1), then sort it by time (eg ORDER BY datetime) and then limit the query to just one item (eg LIMIT 1) and you delete the result of this query. At the end youl get query like this:

```
DELETE FROM LoginTime WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what if there were 2 records for user_id = 1 with the same maximal datetime

Comment: One of them will be deleted... may or may not make sense depending on scenario.

Comment: In this cases I would usually use id instead of a timestamp to determinate the latest one. If id is set to auto-increment, the latest entry in the db will always have the highest id (eg DELETE FROM LoginTime WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: Thanks. it is working. It is difficult to have same datetime for one user in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM logintime t1 
   JOIN 
    (
     SELECT MAX(datetime) 
      AS max_dt 
      FROM logintime 
      WHERE user_id = 1
    ) t2 
WHERE t1.datetime  = t2.max_dt
   AND user_id = 1
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will raise sql error 1093: *You can't specify target table '<that table>' for update in FROM clause*

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is looking complex but useful. I considered simple one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table name
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(primary key)
            FROM table name)
```