# HowTo delete most recent row with Slick 3?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick, typesafe

I have a MySQL table of rows ordered by time.  I want to delete the latest row with Slick 3

In SQL it would look like this (see [How to delete last record(on condition) from a table in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714239/how-to-delete-last-recordon-condition-from-a-table-in-mysql))

```
DELETE FROM Foo ORDER BY DateCreated DESC LIMIT 1
```

I tried this

```
TableQuery[FooTable].sortBy(_.DateCreated.desc).take(1).delete
```

However I got an error that take and drop are not supported by delete.

How do I do this?

Thanks
Peter